# Thread safety of cached ConcurrentHashMaps containing Lists

Tags: java, thread-safety, guava

I'm trying to make a thread safe singleton cache of ConcurrentHashMaps using a Google Guava Cache. Each of these maps will contain a List. The List will only be read ONCE after all threads which could add to it have executed. I'm wondering if my implementation (specifically where I update an item) is thread safe/how to improve it. Is there a better way to do this without using a synchronized block?

```
public enum MyCache {
    INSTANCE;

    private static Cache<Integer, ConcurrentHashMap<String, List>> cache = 
        CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .maximumSize(1000)
            .build();

    private static AtomicInteger uniqueCount = new AtomicInteger(0);

    private final Object mutex = new Object();

        //Create a new unique ConcurrentHashMap
    public Integer newMapItem(){

        Integer key = uniqueCount.incrementAndGet();

        //We dont care if something exists
        cache.put(
            key,
            new ConcurrentHashMap<String, List>()
        );


        return key;
    }

    public void expireMapItem(int key){
        cache.invalidate(key);
    }

    public Integer add(int cacheKey, String mapListKey, int value){

        synchronized(mutex){
            ConcurrentMap<String, List> cachedMap = cache.getIfPresent(cacheKey);
            if (cachedMap == null){
                //We DONT want to create a new map automatically if it doesnt exist
                return null;
            }


            List mappedList = cachedMap.get(mapListKey);

            if(mappedList == null){



                List newMappedList = new List();
                mappedList = cachedMap.putIfAbsent(mapListKey, newMappedList);
                if(mappedList == null){
                    mappedList = newMappedList;
                }
            }
            mappedList.add(value);
            cachedMap.replace(mapListKey, mappedList);

            cache.put(
                cacheKey,
                cachedMap
            );

        }
        return value;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If multiple threads can write to a given `List` (which should be a `List<Integer>`, since you are adding `int`s to it), you'll need to synchronize on something. However, you don't need that global lock. Moreover, you seem to think that `Cache` and `ConcurrentHashMap` copy the objects you put into them and get from them, since you're putting them again once they have been updated, but they don't: they hold references to what you put into them.

I'd change the `add()` method this way:

```
public Integer add(int cacheKey, String mapListKey, int value) {
    // You don't need to synchronize here, since the creation of the map is not
    // synchronized. So either it has been created before, or it hasn't, but there
    // won't be a concurrency problem since Cache is thread-safe.
    ConcurrentMap<String, List<Integer>> cachedMap = cache.getIfPresent(cacheKey);
    if (cachedMap == null){
        // We DON'T want to create a new map automatically if it doesn't exist
        return null;
    }

    // CHM is of course concurrent, so you don't need a synchronized block here
    // either.
    List<Integer> mappedList = cachedMap.get(mapListKey);
    if (mappedList == null) {
        List<Integer> newMappedList = Lists.newArrayList();
        mappedList = cachedMap.putIfAbsent(mapListKey, newMappedList);
        if (mappedList == null) {
            mappedList = newMappedList;
        }
    }

    // ArrayList is not synchronized, so that's the only part you actually need to
    // guard against concurrent modification.
    synchronized (mappedList) {
        mappedList.add(value);
    }

    return value;
}
```

---

Actually, I'd create a `Cache` of `LoadingCache`s, instead of a `Cache` of `ConcurrentHashMap`, it makes the code in `add()` more simple, moving the creation of the `List` to the `CacheLoader` implementation. You can still expose the `LoadingCache`s as `Map`s using the `asMap()` method. I've removed some boxing/unboxing as well.

**EDIT**: changed the return type of `add()` to `boolean` instead of `int` which doesn't work with the original `return null` (when the return type was `Integer`). No need for a potential NPE.

```
public enum MyCache {
    INSTANCE;

    private static Cache<Integer, LoadingCache<String, List<Integer>>> cache =
            CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                    .maximumSize(1000)
                    .build();

    private static AtomicInteger uniqueCount = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public int newMapItem() {
        int key = uniqueCount.incrementAndGet();

        //We dont care if something exists
        cache.put(key, CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(ListCacheLoader.INSTANCE));

        return key;
    }

    public void expireMapItem(int key) {
        cache.invalidate(key);
    }

    public boolean add(int cacheKey, String mapListKey, int value) {
        // You don't need to synchronize here, since the creation of the map is not
        // synchronized. So either it has been created before, or it hasn't, but there
        // won't be a concurrency problem since Cache is thread-safe.
        LoadingCache<String, List<Integer>> cachedMap = cache.getIfPresent(cacheKey);
        if (cachedMap == null) {
            // We DON'T want to create a new map automatically if it doesn't exist
            return false;
        }

        List<Integer> mappedList = cachedMap.getUnchecked(mapListKey);

        // ArrayList is not synchronized, so that's the only part you actually need to
        // guard against concurrent modification.
        synchronized (mappedList) {
            mappedList.add(value);
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static class ListCacheLoader extends CacheLoader<String, List<Integer>> {
        public static final ListCacheLoader INSTANCE = new ListCacheLoader();

        @Override
        public List<Integer> load(String key) {
            return Lists.newArrayList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Especially great to know that I'm dealing with references rather then copies. Implementation with a LoadingCache is definitely much cleaner.